# static variable lifetime and application pool recylcing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, static-variables

I understand the lifetime of static variables in relation to applications (console/windows) but I'm not sure if I am understanding their lifetime when in the context of web apps (asp.net, mvc, web api, etc).

From what I understand, when IIS recycles the app pool, static variables are reset to their type's defaults (integrals = 0, reference types = null, etc), but I'm wondering if inline initializers are re-initialized after recycles or will the type defaults ALWAYS be assigned regardless?

Example(s):

```
// example 1
static class StaticRandom
{
    private static Random rng = new Random();
}
```

In the above, would the static field **rng** be reinitialized to new Random() when called for the first time after a recycle? Or do I need to implement null checks before attempting to use the variable, such as:

```
// example 2
static class StaticRandom
{
    private static Random rng = null;

    public static Next()
    {
        if (rng == null)
            rng = new Random();
        return rng.Next();
    }
}
```

Am I correct in assuming that after an IIS recycle, the **rng** variable in example 1 would be null until reinitialized like in example 2?

**NOTE:** I'm fully aware of the thread safety issues in the above example, it's just a quick example to illustrate my question. In a real-world scenario of the above idea, I would implement a proper locking pattern.

Comment: This wouldn't be such a hard thing to try out yourself. Put a breakpoint in the `Next` method for example 1 and see what you've got as the value for `rng` following a recycle.

Comment: I figured it'd be a lot easier to just ask for clarification rather than loading my local server and twiddling my thumbs for 15 mins while I wait for it to enter a recycle lol. Besides, sometimes people include little gotcha's to keep in mind which are nice to know.

Comment: "wait for it to enter a recycle": Open IIS and recycle the app pool yourself?

Comment: lol zing! It's been a long day...

Comment: lol - I'm in the UK - work out what time it is here!! ;-)

Comment: Could someone elaborate on the `I'm fully aware of the thread safety issues in the above example` note? Whats the proper locking pattern, or what kind of resource could I look up to learn more about this? Thanks!

Comment: @Zorgarath The problem is that two threads could enter the Next method simultaneously before it's initialized, then thread A checks if rng is null, which is true,  and before it can asign a new instance, thread B checks if rng is null which is still true, which will result in one of the two overwriting the rng instance. A simple lock statement would suffice there. This is a good resource to learn synchronization techniques:
http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/NSF-3/e-Book/index.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so couldn't help myself, and did a quick test.

This was pretty much as per your example 1, except with a page output so I could do it without being attached to the process,

It confirmed what I thought - The static will be reset to the inline initialize value.